For a Windows box, with no display visible, stuck at the login screen: how can I clean reboot or shutdown?
Given a Windows 10/11 box that has booted to the user login prompt: How can I cleanly shut it down, if the display is not working?
Win-X+U+U would to this just fine if the machine was logged in.
A combination of tab and enter would work, if the number of users was known in advance.
Is there a reliable key combination for shut down from the login screen?


Hold down the power button for 10 seconds.

Bit of a frame challenge - no video out at all, or no monitor? Something like a cheap USB video adaptor or portable monitor might be an option. I also kind of would consider using narrator, if you have sound/can plug in headphones

I edited the question to specify a clean shutdown.  I have a graphics card that does not always produce a workable display at boot.  The machine is running normally, with a black display.
At that point nothing comes out of the integrated graphics adapter, and basically a reboot is requried.

Try to shutdown from a remote system via:
shutdown /s /m \\<IP Address | FQDN> /t 0


Is that enabled by default on Win 10/11 ?
